# Rails 5 after ran migration limit is gone in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Recently I upgraded my application from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0.3. Then I am trying to run a migration:

```
class AddInvitationToJoinToContests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :goods, :new_field, :string
  end
end
```

The migration ran correctly, but other table fields's `limit` option are gone:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
-    t.string   "name",               limit: 191, null: false
-    t.string   "language",           limit: 191
-    t.string   "image_id",           limit: 191
+    t.string   "name",               null: false
+    t.string   "language"
+    t.string   "image_id"
end
```

Any idea why?

Related issue:

- [Rails 4.2 stops to add limit - rails/rails#19001](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19001)

Comment: Did you find anything about this issue? I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 3):

This could be because Rails 5 does not list the "limit" for columns if the limit matches the default for that column's data type.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/835617b71d2e829c27dbd16a82f22c186c821a0f

You can see in the comments of this changeset that this is to keep the schema.rb database-agnostic.  I would suspect that for whichever database adapter you're using, the default 'limit' for string types is 191.